# Please help: pylint does not work with Emacs23

Tags: python, emacs, pylint

I am trying to use Pylint with Emacs on Windows XP. My Emacs version is EmacsW32 23.1, pylint is 0.21.3 with Python 2.5. After easy_install pylint, I added the following lines to Emacs init file, copied form Emacs Wiki.

When I invoke the flymake-mode on a .py file, I can see the flymake starting the syntax check, the mode status changed to flymake*, and then goes back to flymake after several seconds. But **no error is reported, and no syntax error highlighting**.

I tried to use pylint in command line, and **it works with command "pylint test.py"**, reporting syntax errors on the same file.

I even tried to clear out my .emacs file, but it doesn't help.

Could someone help me on this? Thanks a lot.

> ```
> (when (load "flymake" t)
>   (defun flymake-pylint-init ()
>     (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
>                        'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
>        (local-file (file-relative-name
>                     temp-file
>                     (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
>       (list "epylint" (list local-file))))
>
>   (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
>            '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pylint-init)))
> ```

**Question Update:**
I tried the following at command line prompt with "pylint" and "epylint". Does this mean epylint has a problem?

> ```
> C:\Projects>pylint test_lib.py
> No config file found, using default configuration
> ************* Module test_lib
> E: 13: invalid syntax
>
> C:\Projects>epylint test_lib.py
> 'test_lib.py':1: [F] No module named 'test_lib.py'
>
> C:\Projects>epylint
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python25\Scripts\epylint", line 5, in <module>
>     pkg_resources.run_script('pylint==0.21.3', 'epylint')
>   File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script
>
>     self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
>   File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1207, in run_script
>     execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
>   File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.21.3-py2.5.egg\EGG-INFO\scripts\epylint", line 3, in <module>
>     epylint.Run()
>   File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\pylint-0.21.3-py2.5.egg\pylint\epylint.py", line 93, in Run
>     lint(sys.argv[1])
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program called by flymake should return 0 errorlevel or else flymake thinks there have been problems calling subprocesses.

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259873/how-can-i-use-emacs-flymake-mode-for-python-with-pyflakes-and-pylint-checking-cod/1393590#1393590) and [those patches](http://lists.logilab.org/pipermail/python-projects/2009-September/002039.html), I have managed to run flymake with pylint :

On Windows, but you could do the same kind of thing on Un*x, I have created a batch file `pycheckers.bat` (accessible in your PATH) :

```
pylint -f parseable -r n --disable=C,R,I %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
exit /b 0
```

In my .emacs, I have put those lines :

```
(when (load "flymake" t)
  (defun flymake-pyflakes-init ()
    (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                       'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
           (local-file (file-relative-name
                        temp-file
                        (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
      (list "pycheckers"  (list local-file))))
  (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
               '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pyflakes-init)))
```

Now, when I open a .py file, I do a <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flymake-mode` to activate it. Flymake finds my python errors and warnings without problem.

Note that you can add other tools in the `pycheckers.bat` file.

Comment: Thanks Jerome. It works. But I still don't understand why the installed epylint.bat and epylint does not work.

Comment: epylint.bat:    python "%~dpn0" %*

Comment: epylint:


#!C:\Python25\python.exe
# EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT: 'pylint==0.21.3','epylint'
__requires__ = 'pylint==0.21.3'
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.run_script('pylint==0.21.3', 'epylint')

Comment: Also, all the Pylint output:warnings, errors, conventions are highlighted by the same color. customize-face RET flymake-warnline does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I use emacs22-nox on linux so you may need to google "font-lock-mode" to figure out how to do it on your computer. First enter the emacs command line by pressing `Esc+x`. Now you can type font-lock-mode and hit enter (the command line is at the bottom of the screen). I had the same problem on one my clients servers. Their emacs didn't turn font-lock-mode on by default. Hope that helps.

Comment: The font-lock-mode was turned on. If I enter "font-lock-mode" again, it will be disabled. My color-theme is working with either .el or .py files.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents ...

```
(defun flymake-pylint-init ()
  (list python-python-command
        (list "-m" "pylint.lint" "-f" "parseable" buffer-file-name)))

(add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
              '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pylint-init))
```

tested on WinXP, linux, OS-X.