# How to make Python warn about bad practice and likely mistakes?

Tags: python

Perl has the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas and a couple of CPAN modules for encouraging good style and reducing errors. Is there a Python counterpart that can help me avoid such problems and bad practices while it encourages me to use a more Pythonic structure?

I should make it clear that I do not know what I want to avoid. There is probably a lot of traps to fall into, and I'm not looking for a substitute to reading good code, reading about common errors and writing a lot, but for a complementing automated resource.

Comment: `pylint` `pyflakes` `pychecker`

Comment: It's possible to integrate pylint/pyflakes/pychecker into many different editors / IDEs. I personally use pylint integrated with emacs (flymake-mode) which highlights errors and code cleanliness problems (e.g. unused imports or unused function arguments) as they occur. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259873/how-can-i-use-emacs-flymake-mode-for-python-with-pyflakes-and-pylint-checking-cod

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe pylint (http://www.logilab.org/857) is the most most common tool used for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

The classic style guide for Python is PEP8. If you are interested in style errors, a checker for PEP8 can be found at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8.

Answer (score 2):

googling for Python lint yielded this: http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried "nagging", "strict", "boilerplate" etc. Never heard "lint" in this context -- thanks!

Comment: @Tim: There's some background on the [Wikipedia page for the original `lint`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the -t option to the python interpreter for tab warnings and if you're currently using 2.x and want to minimize the trauma of switching to 3.x in the future, the -3 option will help.

Comment: I just got saved by `-3` thanks to you! Thanks :) "SyntaxWarning: tuple parameter unpacking has been removed in 3.x"